# DATA could not store in database table after code execution

Tags: asp.net

I have a form with input fields and a button.

I want to store the data of form fields in the database on the button click. I wrote code which is executing. There is no error thrown but after the execution the data is not being stored in the database table.

Please help me I am new learner of ASP.NET.

This is the code:

```
/** ===============FORM VALUES IN VARIABLES============= */
            string reg_id = "1";
            string name = TextBox2.Text;
            string email_id = TextBox3.Text;
            string password = TextBox4.Text;           
            string country = DropDownList1.Text;
            string city = DropDownList2.Text;
            string locality = TextBox6.Text;
            /** ==================================================== */
            /** ===============SQL CONNECTION AND QUERY============= */
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Data Source=PERVAIZAHMED-PC/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=jaamepervaiz;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into reg_user_data (reg_id,name,email_id,password,country,city,locality) VALUES ('reg_id','name','email_id','password','country','city','locality');", conn);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@reg_id, reg_id);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@name, name);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@email_id, email_id);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@password, password);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@country, country);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@city, city);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@locality, locality);
            try
           {
               conn.Open();
               sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
           catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
           {
               string msg = "Insert Error:";
               msg += ex.Message;
           }
           finally
           {
               conn.Close();
           }
```

Comment: I think that this "insert into reg_user_data (reg_id,name,email_id,password,country,city,locality) VALUES ('reg_id','name','email_id','password','country','city','locality');" needs to change to this "insert into reg_user_data (reg_id,name,email_id,password,country,city,locality) VALUES ('@reg_id','@name','@email_id','@password','@country','@city','@locality');"

Comment: @TheKingDave you're almost correct. It should be without single quotes `VALUES (@reg_id,@name,@email_id,@password,@country,@city,@locality)`

Comment: @YuriyGalanter a yes whoops forgot to delete them...